# period04 installation problems

Tags: software-installation

I've just successfully installed Period04 in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I've followed each steps carefully given at https://www.univie.ac.at/tops/Period04/faq.html

```
robert@robert-Lenovo-G50-70:~/Downloads$ /home/robert/Downloads/period04-v1.2.0-JRE-linux.sh
-e     ------------------------------------------------------    
-e                      Period04 - Installer                     
-e     ------------------------------------------------------    
-e      Install Period04 in (default: /home/robert): 
-e
-e      Create a link to the Period04 binary in ... 
-e      (default: /home/robert/bin): 
-e     ------------------------------------------------------    
-e      Installing Period04 ...
-e      Installation done. To start Period04 type 'period04'!
```

However, when i tried to open Period04 by typing `period04` on my terminal, I got the following error:

```
robert@robert-Lenovo-G50-70:~/Downloads$ period04
/home/robert/bin/period04: 15: /home/robert/bin/period04: 
/home/robert/Period04/jre/bin/java: not found!
```

I am a newbie, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. It may be trivial for somebody, i expect it to be messing up with java path. If somebody can help me, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Clearly, you did not "follow each steps carefully", or the instructions were wrong. What did you really type? What messages did you see? Please edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/959442/edit ) your post and show us what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE):

`sudo apt install default-jre`

Comment: I have just installed 'jre' by typing on the terminal "sudo apt install default-jre". And it has successfully installed.  But my period04 cannot be started yet. I tried to open the period04 by typing "period04" on the terminal. I gave me the following results.

Comment: If it's saying that java can't be found, you can make a symbolic link to where java is on your system: `ln -s /usr/bin/java /home/robert/Period04/jre/bin/java`. Let me know if you get an error with that command. You might need to make the parent folders with this before: `mkdir -p /home/robert/Period04/jre/bin`.

Comment: By typing "ln -s /usr/bin/java/home/robert/Period04/jre/bin/java"   I got the foolowing error messages:   ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/robert/Period04/jre/bin/java': File exists

Comment: Oh ok, looks like the java binary is already included in there, but just not working. You can move the old binary with `mv /home/robert/Period04/jre/bin/java{,.old}`, then you can run the `ln -s` command.